# Why deep linking not working in Mi Browser?

Tags: java, android, xiaomi

I have Java Android App that associated with my certificated web site by deep link in my AndroidManifest.xml. When this web site is opening in browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc.) it shows "Open In" dialog and navigates to Android App. I tested it in many browsers and it works fine but not in Xiaomi default browser, this browser just opens web site and don't do anything more. It works only if I manualy select url from address bar and choose "Open".

Anyone knows why it could be, does Mi Browser not supporting navigation to apps by deep linking?

I tried to find anything about Mi browser problems with this, but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define both https and app schemas in intent and change your activity launchMode to singleInstance

```xml
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```